# how to use codebehind with a Hub in XAML?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I want to create a Hub in XAML that contains a Grid of my construction

I then want to use code behind to set the values

Mikael Koskinen created a great blog entry (http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-xaml-hub-control-getting-started-tutorial-semanticzoom)

The below sample is 100% his (thanks for the blog) - my question is - is there a better way?

```
<HubSection Header="Trailers">
    <DataTemplate>
        <ListView x:Name="MovieTrailers">

        </ListView>
    </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

> Even though we’ve given the ListView a name, we cannot access it from
>   the code-behind:
>
> This is because the control is inside a DataTemplate. One easy way to
>   get around this limitation is to hook into the ListView’s
>   Loaded-event. Here’s the XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="MovieTrailers" Loaded="MovieTrailers_Loaded">

</ListView>
```

> And the code behind:

```
private void MovieTrailers_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var listView = (ListView)sender;
    listView.ItemsSource = trailers;
}
```

Comment: You can bind the trailers to ItemsSource of ListView in MVVM pattern it looks good..

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and ended up following the [XAML Hub control sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-Hub-control-sample-5d116fa9) to solve it. It uses CollectionViewSource, and I think it's a better way than binding on the Loaded event.

First, define the CollectionViewSource.

```
<Page.Resources>
  <CollectionViewSource x:Name="YourCVS" />
</Page.Resources>
```

On the Hub's ListView bind it to the ItemsSource:

```
<Hub>
  <HubSection Header="ListView">
    <DataTemplate>
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource YourCVS}}">
        <!-- Your code to actually show things -->            
      </ListView>
    </DataTemplate>
  </HubSection>
</Hub>
```

Add the data on code behind:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   // code to populate the data...
   YourCVS.Source = yourListWithData;
}
```

I followed this instructions for my project, but I ended up doing the binding like this:

```
// View constructor
public HubView()
{  
  this.InitializeComponent();
  this.WhenActivated(d =>
  {
    // ViewModel is a property of this view
    d(this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.MyListWithData, x => x.YourCVS.Source));
  });
}
```